# subscribe function causes loop

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, ionic3

I'm trying to use API from cryptocompar to get data.

Updated with more details and removed ngClass from the code.
In test.ts

```
   // data from library page
   coinsGroup = [];

 datainfo: Observable<any>;


  coins:any;

  constructor(public navCtrl: NavController, public navParams: NavParams, public http: HttpClient) 
{
  }


  ionViewDidLoad() 
{

console.log('ionViewDidLoad TestPage');
    this.coinsGroup = this.navParams.data;
  }

 getdetail(coin) {

    this.datainfo = this.http.get("https://min-api.cryptocompare.com/data/pricemultifull?fsyms="+coin+"&tsyms=USD");
    this.datainfo.map(res => res)
    .subscribe(data => {
      this.coins = data['DISPLAY'][coin]['USD']['PRICE']
      console.log('my data: ', this.coins);
    });
  }
```

on test.html

```
 <span *ngIf="coinsGroup.symbol"  class="bold1">

 {{getDetail(coinsGroup.symbol)}}</span>
```

coinsGroup will take symbol from library page such as ['BTC','ETH',..etc]

On the console on chrom it keeps looping as showing below, until browser crash.

[image]

When used subscribe() with map it causes endless loop as showing above, not sure why, and how to solve this problem?

Comment: why call that function in `ngClass`? what is it supposed to set there?

Comment: why are you calling the function in `ngClass` is it necessary? it does not return any boolean value either

Comment: i want to call getdetail() function inside html, to get the data  such as price in USD , high, low  on the html.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes.

`<span [ngClass]="getdetail('BTC')" class="bold1">{{ coins }}</span>`

Is the problem. The `ngClass` tries to set a `string` value for the `class`. (So you can apply css). This is not what you're trying to do, you're trying to retrieve all the coins and then display them.

The way to do this is like so:

```
datainfo: Observable<any>;  
coins:any;

constructor(public navCtrl: NavController, public navParams: NavParams, public http: HttpClient) 
{}
// load the coins after the view is loaded, can also be done on ngOnInit
ionViewDidLoad(){   
    this.getDetail('BTC'); 
}

getdetail(coin) {
    this.datainfo = this.http.get("https://min-api.cryptocompare.com/data/pricemultifull?fsyms="+coin+"&tsyms=USD");
    this.datainfo
      .map(res=>res)
      .subscribe(data => {
        this.coins = data
        console.log('my data: ', this.coins);
    });
}
```

And simply setting

```
<ion-content padding>

  <div style="text-align: center;">
    <!-- the ngIf directive will only show this span if `coins` is defined -->    
    <span *ngIf="coins" class="bold1">{{ coins }}</span> 

</div> 
</ion-content>
```

---

If you want to create more coins, the best practice would probably as follows:

```
  let coinList = ["BTC", "ETH", "LTE"];

  constructor(/* ... */) {}


  getDetail(coin): Observable<any> {
    // don't subscribe, return Observable
    this.http.get("...").map(res=>res);
  }
```

And in your html

```
<ion-content padding>

  <div style="text-align: center;">

    <span *ngFor="let coin of coinList" class="bold1">
       {{ getDetail(coin) | async }}
    </span> 
</div> 
</ion-content>
```

Comment: It is working on test page, but when i  apply on real project it is looping. i will refactor the code and see why it is not working.

Comment: Double check that the old file isn't cached, it looks like you're using chrome so open up chrome devtools (mac) `cmd+opt+i` / Network Tab / Along the top you'll find a disable cache checkbox.

Answer (score 1):

Your view should be passive, it should just display the results. here you're calling a function in the view display which changes the data, which potentialy changes the view, which changes the data...and so on...

Comment: That way i'm getting looping, Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I removed ngClass  as shown above , but still getting loop.

> // data from library page    coinsGroup = [];
>
> datainfo: Observable;
>
> coins:any;
>
> constructor(public navCtrl: NavController, public navParams:
>   NavParams, public http: HttpClient)  {   }
>
> ionViewDidLoad()  {
>
> console.log('ionViewDidLoad TestPage');
>       this.coinsGroup = this.navParams.data;   }
>
> getdetail(coin) {
>
> ```
> this.datainfo = this.http.get("https://min-api.cryptocompare.com/data/pricemultifull?fsyms="+coin+"&tsyms=USD");
> this.datainfo.map(res => res)
> .subscribe(data => {
>   this.coins = data['DISPLAY'][coin]['USD']['PRICE']
>   console.log('my data: ', this.coins);
> });   }
> ```

on test.html

*ngIf="coinsGroup.symbol"  class="bold1">

{{getDetail(coinsGroup.symbol)}}

[image]